# A Database Error Occurred: You must use the "set" method to update an entry

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou usando Codeigniter e estou cadastrando uma chamada no banco e recebo a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 public function solicitacaoRapida(){

            $banco = array(
            'solicitante'   => $this->input->post('empresaSolicitante'),
            'local'     => $this->input->post('localEmpresa'),
            'departamento'  => $this->input->post('nomeDepartamento'),
            'assunto'   => $this->input->post('tipoSolicitacao')
        );

            $this->db->insert('solicitacoes',$this);

            redirect(base_url().'home','refresh');

        }
```

Comment: Para gravar vc n deveria passar $banco no lugar de $this

Comment: Como ? Eu escrevi esta funcão no controlador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos formatos esperado pelo méotodo `insert()` é um array associativo. Na chamada atual do código você passa as informações do controller(`$this`) quando o esperado seria `$banco`.

Mude:

```
$this->db->insert('solicitacoes', $this);
```

Para:

```
$this->db->insert('solicitacoes', $banco);
```